# Passing arguments on a jnlp file

Tags: java, deployment, javafx, jnlp

Is it possible to pass maven-like arguments on a JNLP file?

```
   <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="${javafxCodebase}" href="Foo.jnlp">
   <information>
      <title>${javafxTitle}</title>
      <vendor>${javafxVendor}</vendor>
       ...
   </information>
   ... 
   </jnlp>
```

And if so, who will pass these data to the jnlp file? What comes to mind is:

```
   http://localhost:8080/Foo.jnlp?javafxCodebase=bar&javafxTitle=baz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for this out of the box with Java Webstart. There is a [JNLP Download Servlet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) but it only supports a limited set of macros and cannot have any that are user defined.

I think your best approach would be to use a templating engine like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) to write your own servlet for generating the JNLP file on the fly and populating it with your required arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the php script on [this website](http://www.digitalgemstones.com/code/tools/jnlp.php).

I found it useful to automatically detect my codebase url, since I had a requirement to deploy the jnlp files on different servers.